# Add HEADER in HTTP Request in Java

Tags: java, sockets, httprequest

I'm using this following code to send simple HTTP Request :

```
try
{
    Socket  s = new Socket ();
    s.bind    (new InetSocketAddress (ipFrom, 0));
    s.connect (new InetSocketAddress (ipTo,   80), 1000);

    PrintWriter     writer = new PrintWriter    (s.getOutputStream ());
    BufferedReader  reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (s.getInputStream ()));

    writer.print ("GET " + szUrl + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"); 
    writer.flush ();

    s     .close ();
    reader.close ();
    writer.close ();
}
```

However, as you can see, I don't send a custom HEADER.
What should I add to send a custom HEADER ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
writer.print ("GET " + szUrl + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
```

The `\r\n\r\n` bit is sending a line-feed/carriage-return to end the line and then another one to indicate that there are no more headers.  This is a standard in both HTTP and email formats, i.e. a blank line indicates the end of headers.  In order to add additional headers you just need to not send that sequence until you're done.  You can do the following instead

```
writer.print ("GET " + szUrl + " HTTP/1.0\r\n"); 
writer.print ("header1: value1\r\n"); 
writer.print ("header2: value2\r\n"); 
writer.print ("header3: value3\r\n"); 
// end the header section
writer.print ("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to implement the HTTP protocol yourself.

Use [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) by Apache.

(or its older and a little easier to use version - [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/))

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this advice. It seems to be very simple and powerful !

Answer (score 1):

Even if I suggest to try HttpComponents as mentioned by Bozho instead of implementing HTTP by yourself, this is would be the way to add a custom header:

```
 writer.print ("GET " + szUrl + " HTTP/1.0\r\n"); 
 writer.print ("X-MyOwnHeader: SomeValue\r\n");
```

Comment: Specifically, the end of the header section is denoted by "\r\n\r\n", so whatever the last header line is should end in that, or should be followed by another line saying `writer.print("\r\n");`

Comment: Almost right, you just need another `writer.print("\r\n");` at the end to finish the header part.

Answer (score 1):

You should use classes already prepared to be used for http connections, like `HTTPUrlConnection` that is a childreon of `UrlConnection` and has this method

```
void setRequestProperty(String key, String value)
```

that should be used to set parameters of the request (like **HEADER** field).. check [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) for reference

Comment: Not if your intent is to learn a lower level abstraction of computer science.

Answer (score 1):

You can also see URLConnection.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: Hi, I can't really use URLConnection because I need to bind to a local IP. My server have 5 ips, and I need to send my Request from on of this.

Comment: @billOute - what?  A URLConnection is perfectly capable of dealing with that.  You just need to use different IP addresses in the URLs!!

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to do it yourself by hand it must follow this format with each header on its own line.

> name: value

Look into the header format in HTTP spec.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#Message-Headers