# Can I set the session state between client and server (socket) using a cookie or some other session variable

Tags: java, sockets, session, cookies

So, here is my issue ... I was given the code Server Side and Client side, I am using Sockets to communicate. The requirement was to identify the client using a cookie, but it seems that I need to use HTTP Servlet in order to do this, so is there any way to capture the session variables (most importantly, identifying the client) at the server level?

Comment: Are you looking to find a custom cookie in the request object, or are you looking to get a session using the JSESSIONID cookie? If the former, I can provide some code, if the later, it should be handled automatically by your container.

Comment: this is for a homework assignment ... my guess is it would be the later ... because we are NOT using HTTPServlets and JSP, there are two java programs communicating using sockets ... As each thread is created, we need to identify the client so each time they connect, we can continue.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java sockets use TCP connections, you're just writing back and forth a stream of data. I do not believe there is any type of additional features that would provide this support automatically. I think you would have to roll your own solution, possibly creating a customized concept of a "header" for your request. You would probably have to use some type of encryption to prevent spoofing the session.

This SO question includes (what appears to be) a simple example of putting a header at the beginning of the stream sent to the socket.

[Add HEADER in HTTP Request in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214308/add-header-in-http-request-in-java)

Comment: I think I am on to something ... I may be making this more complicated then it is. Thanks for all your help. much appreciated.